# How could the emacs not load some .el files while initializing?

Tags: emacs

I put each type emacs settings into some single files, like load-cygwin.el, load-cedet.el etc. And use a subverion to share them everywhere and everytime.

Now for load-cygwin.el, it's only need on Windows platform, but every-time I sync these configurations in Linux platform, I have to remove them.

How could the emacs not load the load-cygwin.el file while initializing? I need some conditions to jump out the file?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to deal with it. One way (which I use)

I assagin a name for each system based on the hostname. (you can also define checking window system/emacs vesrion/OS and so on..)

```
 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  define systems ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

 (defvar on-laptop          ; on my laptop, mostly I can run everything
   (string-match "rag" (system-name)))

 (defvar on-lab-computer                 ; main lab desktop
   (string-match "okho" (system-name)))

 (defvar on-lab-server        ; lab cluster
   (string-match "amu" (system-name)))


 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; Usage ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
 (when on-laptop
 ;;; music / emms config
   (load "emms-config.el"))


 ; load work related stuff
 (when on-lab-computer
   ;; load work related

    )


 (when (not on-lab-server)
   ;;; some setup that are unnecessary on cluster, but useful on remaining systems

   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Read through at least the first two of these:

- http://brain-break.blogspot.co.nz/2010/08/determining-running-environment-and.html
- [How to detect that emacs is in terminal-mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795451/how-to-detect-that-emacs-is-in-terminal-mode)
- [even when emacsclient is started in a terminal, window-system is non-nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616761/even-when-emacsclient-is-started-in-a-terminal-window-system-is-non-nil)

Answer (score 0):

For OS-dependent settings, check the [`system-type` variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/System-Environment.html#index-system_002dtype-3760):

```
(and (memq system-type '(cygwin windows-nt))
     (load "load-cygwin"))
```

Another way to handle conditional requirements is to use the [`locate-library` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Library-Search.html#index-locate_002dlibrary-809) to see if the file exists.  (This assumes that `load-cygwin.el` is not present on your Linux machines.)

```
(and (locate-library "load-cygwin")
     (load "load-cygwin"))
```

Another useful variable for this sort of conditional requirement is [`window-system`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Systems.html#index-window_002dsystem-3695).